# SQL Server: is there a way to prevent user from seeing all databases in an instance?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to prevent that a user sees all databases in an instance? I tried to deny this from user 'mark' by

```
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO mark
```

but this prevented him to see (in the SSMS Object Explorer) also the database he is attached to (as a db_reader).

Comment: Then why do they have access in the first place?  I think you need to provide more information about what you're wanting to do

Comment: I want that he can view only his database in the database list in SSMS object explorer, not all of the databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO public` because "mark" is a member of public (as are all logins). [Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20150706044943/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/euanga/archive/2006/05/04/585513.aspx)

You don't remove rights for logins indivially because then all rights are lost even where expected.

Generally, if a login has permissions on an object (database, table, whatever) they can see that object in Object Explorer in SSMS

Edit: it's not foolproof and the database owner needs changed. Sorry, forgot about that.

Even if the DB is visible, no rights are conferred or implied.

Comment: So you're saying that what I'm trying to do is not possible in SQL Server (2008)?

Comment: Sorry it it isn't obvious Yes youcan but deny to public

Comment: But if I deny from public the user "mark" still don't see the database he is attached to. All the databases will disappear from the Object Explorer.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189077.aspx you'd need to make mark the owner of the database: I forgot that, sorry

Comment: Thanks, there stands: To limit visibility to database metadata, deny a login the VIEW ANY DATABASE permission. After this permission is denied, a login can see only metadata for master, tempdb, and databases that the login owns. So this is all about the metadata (sys schema), this does not say anything about the visibility of the databases in the object explorer.

Comment: I gave "mark" db_owner rights to one database, and still all the databases will disappear from the Object Explorer for user "mark".

Comment: The command to change the owner of the db is: `sp_changedbowner newUserName` - You need to be sysadmin and have the db in question be the "current one", also delete the user from the db before running the command

Comment: The combination of `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO public` and `sp_changedbowner newUserName` makes newUserName only able to see that one db

Comment: That does not work on Azure SQL. It returns an error "Securable class 'server' not supported in the server scope in this version of SQL Server.
"